# What redistributable are need for my program?

Tags: steam, redistributable

I've just uploaded a build of my program to Steam for review and they cannot run it (no errors, nothing).

Steam Support sends back a form letter without any useful information, and response times when I ask a question are slow and vague.

Every system I have access to will run it (after installing 2 redistributable that I know are needed).

I've setup my Steam build to install the 2 redistributable.

If I download the build from Steam, it works fine.

I know this is an odd question, but is there any good ways of finding out what Steam support is missing on their systems that my program needs, i.e., how can I find out what my program needs that clean installs of windows may not have?

Or is there something else I am missing that may cause this problem when distributing a program?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  I've been trying for days to find any information, but have found nothing, and when the program works with all my system, it is hard to debug a problem that I can't recreate.

I've uploaded 2 builds of the exe to Steam with the same results.  The second build should have opened the debug file if the program ran and failed to initialize.  Seeing how Steam says they get no error this would point to the program not being able to be started by Windows, which I think would point to a missing redistributable.